# Target variable directly dependent on feature

Tags: nonlinear-regression, feature-engineering

Suppose a target of interest A and a feature B which serves as a good predictor for A. (both continuous variables)

In literature, the target is always reported as C := A/B however.

For me it is not particularly important if I can predict either A or C, but I fear multiplication of B times C to obtain A leads to a much larger range of values (magnitudes), such that the model would have difficulty to predict the really large values.

Is it legit to predict C instead of A using B as one of the predictors, knowing the direct dependence?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.